# apache access log high byte size returned to client

Tags: php, apache, access-log

I can see this in my access log

```
66.102.6.215 - - [27/Oct/2016:05:05:27 +0000] "GET /wp-content/cache/minify/d9389.css HTTP/1.1" 200 80460 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SAMSUNG-SM-G935A Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

I can see the file size response to the client is around 80kb is this accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) is probably this one :

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

The number 80460 correspond to `%O`. According to the documentation :

> %O
>   Bytes sent, including headers. May be zero in rare cases such as when a request is aborted before a response is sent.

It means that the size of the request is 80460 bytes, this is about 78.6 KB (kilobytes) which is about 0.08 MB (megabytes).